# How to specify requirements in Python packages metadata

Tags: python, metadata, setuptools, pypi, distutils

[Core metadata specification](https://packaging.python.org/specifications/core-metadata/#requires-external-multiple-use) documents the metadata field *Requires-External* which seems to be for specifying system (non-python) dependencies.

How do you actually specify this field though? This is what I've tried:

```
.
├── mypackage
│   └── __init__.py
└── setup.py
```

Contents of `setup.py`

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name="mypackage",
    description="blah blah",
    url='https://example.org',
    version="0.1",
    packages=["mypackage"],
    requires_external=[
        "C",
        "libpng (>=1.5)",
        'make; sys_platform != "win32"',
    ],
)
```

When I build this package, that metadata was not included

```
Metadata-Version: 2.1
Name: mypackage
Version: 0.1
Summary: blah blah
Home-page: https://example.org
License: UNKNOWN
Platform: UNKNOWN

UNKNOWN
```

So what is the syntax to pass *Requires-External* to setuptools/distutils? Note: this question is not asking about *Requires-Dist* metadata.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So what is the syntax to pass Requires-External to setuptools/distutils?

There is none by default, as neither `distutils` nor `setuptools` support the field. Also, `requires_external` keyword arg is not supported as well - it is silently ignored, just as any other unknown keyword arg.

To add local support for `requires_external` kwarg, you need to provide your own distribution implementation. Minimal example (requires Python 3.9):

```
from setuptools.dist import Distribution as DistributionOrig

class Distribution(DistributionOrig):
    _DISTUTILS_UNSUPPORTED_METADATA = DistributionOrig._DISTUTILS_UNSUPPORTED_METADATA | {'requires_external': dict}
```

You can now pass `requires_external` to `setup()` when paired with `distclass`:

```
setup(
    ...,
    requires_external=[
        'C',
        'libpng (>=1.5)',
        'make; sys_platform != "win32"',
    ],
    distclass=Distribution,
)
```

The next goal is to actually write the contents of `requires_external` to `PKG-INFO`. This is quite tricky to do via distribution metadata itself because `setuptools` patches the relevant methods (`DistributionMetadata.read_pkg_file()` and `DistributionMetadata.write_pkg_file()`) with own monolithic impls. The easiest way for this IMO is to modify `PKG-INFO` post factum via a custom `egg_info` impl:

```
import email
from pathlib import Path
from setuptools.command.egg_info import egg_info as egg_info_orig


class egg_info(egg_info_orig):
    def run(self):
        super().run()
        # PKG-INFO is now guaranteed to exist
        pkg_info_file = Path(self.egg_info, 'PKG-INFO')
        pkg_info = email.message_from_bytes(pkg_info_file.read_bytes())
        for req in self.distribution.metadata.requires_external:
            pkg_info.add_header('Requires-External', req)
        pkg_info_file.write_bytes(pkg_info.as_bytes())
```

Pass your own `egg_info` impl via `cmdclass` argument in `setup()`:

```
setup(
    ...,
    requires_external=[
        'C',
        'libpng (>=1.5)',
        'make; sys_platform != "win32"',
    ],
    distclass=Distribution,
    cmdclass={'egg_info': egg_info},
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. This actually worked for a bdist_wheel, but it didn't quite work for the sdist. It has made two different PKG-INFO files inside the .tar.gz, one is at the root and one is in an .egg-info subdirectory, and only one of those files had the Requires-External metadata. Also it seems kind of intrusive (monkeypatch on top of a monkeypatch!), are you sure all of those parts of setuptools are public API?  `_DISTUTILS_UNSUPPORTED_METADATA` in particular has an underscore prefix.

Comment: _It has made two different PKG-INFO files inside the .tar.gz_ - this is part of `distutils` and has nothing to do with the code in the answer. Running `python -c 'from setuptools import setup; setup()' sdist` in an empty directory will write two `PKG-INFO` files in the source dist as well.

Comment: _Also it seems kind of intrusive (monkeypatch on top of a monkeypatch!)_ - I don't monkeypatch anywhere in the code. What are you talking about?

Comment: _are you sure all of those parts of setuptools are public API?_ Yes, I'm aware of using parts of the private API, that's why I noted this is a _minimal example_, as you will hardly manage to write it shorter. If you'd want to do it all explicit and long way, you'd write a `Distribution.__init__` method, read and validate the custom kwargs from `attrs` and reassign them in metadata. I just took the shortcut for the demonstration purposes.

Comment: I see.  I'm kind of surprised there is this field in the core metadata specification but zero support for it in the tooling, don't you think that's a bit strange? I'll accept this answer, but I think if it's not too much trouble can you update the code so that it doesn't write two _different_ PKG-INFO files inside the dist. If there have to be two of them, they should at least have the same metadata otherwise it's error prone (getting different metadata depending on which PKG-INFO file you chose to use?).